# Output timezone with Matlab datestr()

Tags: matlab, datetime, timezone

Very simple question.  I'm using Matlab's [datetime](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datetime.html) type, so I can carry timezone information.  I need to get a specific string representation, to input into a DB.  But [datestr()](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datestr.html) does not have any fields to output tz info.

```
a = datetime('now', 'TimeZone', 'UTC');

%need output in the format 'YYYYMMDDTHH:MM:SS+00:00'
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the output you want by setting the [`Format` property](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datetime.html#property_d119e193218) of the [`datetime`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datetime.html) object to display the time zone offset, converting it to a [character array](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/char.html), then [replacing the space](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strrep.html) by `'T'`:

```
>> a = datetime('now', 'TimeZone', 'UTC', 'Format', 'yyyyMMdd HH:mm:SSxxxxx')

a = 

  datetime

   20171002 21:37:74+00:00

>> out = strrep(char(a), ' ', 'T')

out =

20171002T21:37:74+00:00
```

Also, take note of the case of the letters in the format string, as that matters for some of them.